# mod_rewrite rule breaks when adding trailing slash 2 subdirectories deep

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm very, very new to mod rewrite rules, and having trouble with one I'm using to redirect a site previously hosted in a subdirectory to a new domain. Here's the rule I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /oldsite/ #also tried this without the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^.* http://newsite.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

This works perfectly until you get 3 levels deep and add a trailing slash to the redirected url. So, the results look like this:

- olddomain.com/oldsite redirects to newsite.com [CORRECT]
- olddomain.com/oldsite/ redirects to newsite.com [CORRECT]
- olddomain.com/oldsite/subdirectory redirects to newsite.com/subdirectory [CORRECT]
- olddomain.com/oldsite/subdirectory/ redirects to newsite.com [INCORRECT!]

I feel like I'm 99% there, but pulling my hair out a bit figuring out that last little bit. Any idea what I need to change?

Thanks!

Also, I tested placing the .htaccess file in the public html folder as well as in the /oldsite folder and there are no other htaccess files elsewhere on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, put this in the .htaccess in /oldsite on your server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^.*) http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

When you put the regex to match in parenthesis, it becomes available to use as $1. If you have more than one, $1 is the first, $2 the second, etc.

I suggest reading the manual page for mod_rewrite, specifically the rewriterule section (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply, Brady. That works also (and fixes another issue I just realized I had where a url that would produce a 404 on the old site would redirect to the home page of the new site), but still runs into the same issue: adding the trailing slash to the last example still redirects to the home page.

Will read some more, but didn't see anything on the page you referenced that pertains to this specific instance.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache before testing it? Sometimes browsers hold onto those redirects. I just tested it again locally.

Comment: Ha. Yep, that fixed it. Whoops. Problem solved; thanks Brady!